# Ошибка редиректа страниц каталога в Bitrix после перехода на https

Tags: .htaccess, битрикс

Столкнулся с проблемой: после прописывания в `.htaccess` редиректа с `http` на `https` внутренние страницы каталога перенаправляются на 404 страницу. Из найденного в сети, главным виновником пока назначил механизм ЧПУ Bitrix. 
Пробовал несколько разных правил перенаправления, пробовал размещать их до, после, до и после правил ЧПУ Bitrix. Резултат тот-же  - 404 страница 
Без редиректа в `.htaccess` эти самые внутренние страницы каталога удачно отображаются как при `http`, так и при `https` протоколе. 
Подскажите в чём ошибка, не дайте помереть дурой.
Штакес (исходный, редирект на `https` закоментирован ):

```html
php_value auto_prepend_file "/home/user2050118/www/lor_protect/lor_o.php"

Options -Indexes 
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_flag session.use_trans_sid off
  #php_value display_errors 1
  #php_value mbstring.internal_encoding UTF-8
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On

#RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
#RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

 # редирект c www на без www  
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]     
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
 # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs     
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]     
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/bitrix/.* [NC]     
  RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
# Removes index.html from ExpressionEngine URLs     
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.html [NC]     
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/bitrix/.* [NC]     
  RewriteRule (.*?)index\.html/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
 # редирект /news -> /news/  
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*/[^/\.]+)$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [R=301,L]  
 # дублирующие слеши
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?)/{2,}(.*?/{2,}.*?)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?)/{2,}(.*?)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
  
 # подключение ЧПУ битрикса 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/bitrix/urlrewrite.php$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bitrix/urlrewrite.php [L]
  RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_dir.c>
  DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive on
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 3 day"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 3 day"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 3 day"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 3 day"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 3 day"  
</IfModule>
```

Правила urlrewrite.php

```html
<?
$arUrlRewrite = array(
 array(
  "CONDITION" => "#^/countries/#",
  "RULE" => "",
  "ID" => "bitrix:catalog",
  "PATH" => "/countries/america.php",
 ),
 array(
  "CONDITION" => "#^/countries/#",
  "RULE" => "",
  "ID" => "bitrix:catalog",
  "PATH" => "/countries/africa.php",
 ),
 array(
  "CONDITION" => "#^/countries/#",
  "RULE" => "",
  "ID" => "bitrix:catalog",
  "PATH" => "/countries/index.php",
 ),
 array(
  "CONDITION" => "#^/countries/#",
  "RULE" => "",
  "ID" => "bitrix:catalog",
  "PATH" => "/countries/evropa.php",
 ),
 array(
  "CONDITION" => "#^/countries/#",
  "RULE" => "",
  "ID" => "bitrix:catalog",
  "PATH" => "/countries/australia.php",
 ),
 array(
  "CONDITION" => "#^/countries/#",
  "RULE" => "",
  "ID" => "bitrix:catalog",
  "PATH" => "/countries/azia.php",
 ),
 array(
  "CONDITION" => "#^/news/#",
  "RULE" => "",
  "ID" => "bitrix:news",
  "PATH" => "/news/index.php",
 )
);

?>
```

Сам поциент: http://vsevizy.by

Comment: @zhurof подскажите удалось решить вопрос?

Comment: подскажите удалось решить вопрос? Вопрос от @ArtyomBolshakov

Comment: @ArtyomBolshakov, Jigius мне предложил решение по настройке редиректа в конфигурационном файле `Nginx`, но проверить не получилось, т.к. к нему у меня не было доступа.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите тот эту [страницу документации](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/reference/cmain/ishttps.php)

Обратите внимание на первый комментарий. У меня была подобная проблема. Исправил  установкой переменной "https_request" в .settings.php

```
 'https_request' =>
    array(
        'value' => true,
    )
```

Comment: К сожалению, установка переменной `https_request` не помогла

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте редирект сделать так:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

`%{SERVER_NAME}` - имя хоста в настройках HTTP-сервера и оно, скорее всего, отличается у вас от имени сайта, для которого вы делаете редирект. Используйте `%{HTTP_HOST}`

Comment: Не помогло. Склоняюсь к тому, что дело не в правиле .htaccess, а в компоненте Bitrix, ведь остальные страницы редиректит нормально

Comment: В броузере, в консоли  разработчика, при таком неработающем редиректе (когда возвращается страница с  404-ошибкой) - проверьте  значение у заголовка `Location`  в ответе вашего запроса. И ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО почистите кеш у броузера - 301 ответ кешируется

Comment: `Location {replace: ƒ, href: "https://vsevizy.by/bitrix/urlrewrite.php", ancestorOrigins: DOMStringList, origin: "https://vsevizy.by", protocol: "https:", …}`

Comment: Я имел ввиду заголовок Location у http-ответа (закладка network)

Comment: типа такого: ```HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Fri, 19 Apr 2019 06:30:24 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Location: http://acc.misc.creachoo.ru/fo4
Content-Length: 325
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1```

Comment: Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 224
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Date: Fri, 19 Apr 2019 06:43:01 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Location: https://vsevizy.by/bitrix/urlrewrite.php
Server: nginx/1.14.2

Comment: И `general headers` : Request URL: https://vsevizy.by/countries/viza-v-kitay/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 302 Found
Remote Address: 178.159.243.85:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Comment: Странно, что сервер `nginx`. Насколько я знаю, `.htaccess` - конфигурационный файл для `apache`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92638/discussion-between-jigius-and-zhurof).